# Create a video or folder which will be available for particular time only

Tags: security, video, locking, directory, television

We want to develop one video or folder containing videos/images/content to be played on TV (not smart TV) in offline mode. But it should be played for some particular time only lets say a year. After that user need to contact admin or subscribe to view the same again. Is it possible to do the same and if yes what are the ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Most DRM systems, such as Widevine, PlayReady and FPS support what you are asking for - offline playback with a limit on the duration.

When the client requests the license, the response it receives includes the decryption key and some metadata about the entitlements. This metadata allows the client be granted entitlements such as offline playback and allows a time limit be set for that capability.

As an example, look at the PlayReady license template information here and at the linked 'Compliance Rules for PlayReady Products' document which is publicly available online:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-playready-license-template-overview